# Magento Community 1.6.2 Different Responses from Servers

Tags: php, api, magento, soap, wsdl

I am making a call 'catalogProductAttributeSetList' against two different Magento Community 1.6.2 installs and they are returning results in a different format.

**Server 1**

WSDL: www.indo-pac.biz/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1
PHPINFO: www.indo-pac.biz/info.php

Response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"           xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
     <ns1:catalogProductAttributeSetListResponse>
     <result SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns1:catalogProductAttributeSetEntity[2]" xsi:type="ns1:catalogProductAttributeSetEntityArray">
        <item xsi:type="ns1:catalogProductAttributeSetEntity">
           <set_id xsi:type="xsd:int">9</set_id>
           <name xsi:type="xsd:string">Cameras</name>
        </item>
        <item xsi:type="ns1:catalogProductAttributeSetEntity">
           <set_id xsi:type="xsd:int">4</set_id>
           <name xsi:type="xsd:string">Default</name>
        </item>
     </result>
  </ns1:catalogProductAttributeSetListResponse>
```

** Server 2**

WSDL: http://magento.a-dot.co.uk/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1
phpinfo: http://s33667.gridserver.com/gs-bin/phpinfo.php-stable

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"       xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento" xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:SOAP-  ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:catalogProductAttributeSetListResponse>
  <result SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns2:Map[2]"   xsi:type="ns1:catalogProductAttributeSetEntityArray">
        <item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
      <item>
        <key xsi:type="xsd:string">set_id</key>
        <value xsi:type="xsd:string">4</value>
      </item>
      <item>
        <key xsi:type="xsd:string">name</key>
        <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Default</value>
      </item>
    </item>
    <item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
      <item>
        <key xsi:type="xsd:string">set_id</key>
        <value xsi:type="xsd:string">9</value>
      </item>
      <item>
        <key xsi:type="xsd:string">name</key>
        <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Ladies Shoes</value>
      </item>
    </item>
  </result>
</ns1:catalogProductAttributeSetListResponse>
```

Can someone explain why the results are different? The request is exactly the same. I'm using soapUI 4.0.1 to verify the responses sent (I've also witnessed it using Java)

I suspect its a mismatch of SOAP libraries on the servers but how can this be verified?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Magento has two different modes for their v2 SOAP API.  My guess would be one server is in "WS-I" mode, and the other isn't.  Have the administrator of the stores in question check the setting at

```
System -> Configuration -> Services -> Magento Core API -> WS-I Compliance
```

Comment: Hi Alan, I have already checked - both stores have WS-I Compliance set to NO

Comment: Make sure you check at the various store configuration levels as well (that said, it could countless other things)

Comment: @Alan - Yes, you're right, the output of the second Server do resemble the **WS-I** mode as enabled.

Comment: I have confirmed that the setting is definitely set to NO in the UI - could it be that the setting is cached? your help is appreciated!

Comment: Alan, if you have a 1.6.2 Community store I would appreciate it if you could make the same API call and see what format the data is returned to you?

Answer (score 1):

The response from the server 2 is getting by enabling WSI compliance. Please make sure you refresh the cache. You can double check by calling Mage::getStoreConfig('api/config/compalince_wsi') on server 2  and print out what is the return.
I checked the data on CE 1.6.2 and receive the first response by disabling of WSI compliance and the second response by enabling of WSI compliance.